# Xamarin forms - Loading ImageSource from Blob storage

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms, imagesource, azure-blob-storage

I'm facing a somewhat weird issue.
I have a simple code (I guess) in my Xamarin Forms project to take pictures thanks to the great plugin.Media which allows cross platform picture capture:

```
public async Task<CameraResult> TakeCrossPictureAsync()
{
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);

    CameraResult res = new CameraResult()
    {
        Picture = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path),
        FilePath = file.Path,
        Name = await this.UploadFileAsync(file.GetStream())
    };
}
```

When I do this, I'm able to display the Image with this line in my ViewModel which is bound to an `FFImageLoading:CachedImage`

```
CameraResult camRes = await picManager.TakeCrossPictureAsync();
    if (camRes != null)
        this.Picture = camRes.Picture;
```

The "Picture" attribute is a Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.
I then navigate to another page, passing the ImageSource as an argument and I'm able to display it in another `FFImageLoading:CachedImage` :

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Picture}" LoadingPlaceholder="loading.png" CacheDuration="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

No problem there, everything is working like a charm.
But, when I try to do the same thing by downloading the image from a Blob storage :

```
public async Task<ImageSource> GetFileAsync(string name)
{
    var blob = this.container.GetBlobReference(name);
    if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
    {
        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
        byte[] blobBytes = new byte[blob.Properties.Length];

        await blob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(blobBytes, 0);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(blobBytes);
        return(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
    }
}
```

The Imagesource returned is bound to the same `FFImageLoading:CachedImage` in the first and second view.

The problem is that it displays perfectly in the first view but when I pass the `ImageSource` as an argument to the second ViewModel, the image does not show in the UWP project and displays the LoadingPlaceHolder or I get an unhandled exception on Android.

Is anyone able to tell me how the two `ImageSources` differ and why it is displayed from the file in the second view but not from the blob ?

Thank you in advance !